Remove altitude "outliers" from a GPS track
I've recorded a bike track with a very noisy result for altitude (barometric sensor). I enhanced the altitude data using a digital elevation model. See example here:

However, crossing bridges or tunnels introduces "outliers" that do not accurately reflect the actual profile of my ride. Is there any way to remove these outliers? I aim to achieve a result similar to the red lines in the picture below:

Raw data:
distance,altitude
0.0,142.27000427246094
0.0,142.27000427246094
0.0,142.27000427246094

Full data here: https://pastebin.com/Tf1vxFNT

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com or dsp.stackexchange.com. The right way to go about any outlier problem is to have a model for the usual measurement and one or more models for unusual measurements. Here the usual measurement model might be "the road has slope less than 6%" plus "GPS error is +/- nnn % with positive and negative equally likely" (I don't know if that's actually the case). From that you would work out the posterior probability of usual vs unusual and derive a rule from that.

Heuristics for filtering are essentially making such assumptions and just jumping over the intermediate results -- my advice is to explicitly state the models and work through the steps to get to your decision rule.
